# $(g_1 g_2)^m = g_1^m g_2^m \Leftrightarrow g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$ -- Question from Mac Lane and Birkhoff (Chapter II, section 3, problem 7)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm still working through Mac Lane and Birkhoff and I have another question. The question is: In a group $G$, show that
$$
(g_1 g_2)^m = g_1^m g_2^m
$$
for all integers $m$ if and only if $g_1 g_2 = g_2 g_1$.

It's pretty clear that if we assume that $g_1$ and $g_2$ then the above is true. However, I'm getting stuck trying show in the other direction. What I've been trying is to start with 
$$
(g_1 g_2)^m = g_1 g_1 g_1 \cdots g_2 g_2 g_2
$$
and then somehow cancel terms to arrive at the desired result of $g_1 g_2$ on the LHS and $g_2 g_1$ on the RHS (as this is pretty clear and works nicely when $m =2$). Is this the way to go about it, or is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

For $m=2$ we get
$$
abab = (ab)^2 = a^2 b^2 = aabb \iff abab = aabb
$$
premultiply by $a^{-1}$ and postmultiply by $b^{-1}$ to get $ba=ab$.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to work through the case when $m=2$, but I could not get this same technique to work for generic $m$. For example, when you multiply by $a^{-1}$ on the left and $b^{-1}$, the result is $bababa\cdots a = a a \cdots b$ (now with $m-1$ terms on each side). From here, if you multiply by $b^{-1}$ on the left, then it does cancel the $b$ on the LHS, but you end up with $b^{-1} a a \cdots b$ on the RHS. This is where I get stuck.

Comment: @raynea you don't need to do it for each $m$, -- since you know it for all $m$, in particular, $m=2$ holds

Comment: Ah right! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you take $m = -1$, we get that
$$(g_1g_2)^{-1} = g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1} = (g_2g_1)^{-1}$$(Check the last equality).
Since a group element times its inverse is the identity (denote it by $e$), we have
$$e = (g_1g_2)(g_1g_2)^{-1} = (g_1g_2)(g_2g_1)^{-1}$$
Thus, by mutiplying by $(g_2g_1)$ on the right, we conclude that
$(g_1g_2) = (g_2g_1)$.